# Repeating glow animation outside radius (like bulb glowing effect)

Tags: core-animation

I am working on iPad project and I need to do animation like glowing bulb with smooth ON/ OFF effect. How can I achieve this?

[image: example image]

Comment: Have you tried CABasicAnimation?

Comment: No, I never used CABasicAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with UIView animation and try to get same kind of animation.

Here is code which I tried.

```
-(void) setGlowToView{

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width-7.f)/2.f, (self.frame.size.height-7.f)/2.f, 7.f, 7.f)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self addSubview:view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

    view.alpha = 0.8;
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.2;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.8,1.8);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
}
```